# Free XML Control (WPF or Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xml, winforms

I am looking for a **free control** (WPF or Windows Forms) for **displaying XML** in a Windows application. For some reasons I don't want to use the Webbrowser control. It should similar to the visualization within the **XML Explorer on Codeplex** ([xmlexplorer.codeplex.com](http://xmlexplorer.codeplex.com/)). The control should not have a classical GNU licence, but rather a liberal licence.

Answer (score 6):

Try [AvalonEditor](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/AvalonEdit). this one has most of fileformat supported with formatting  and alots of things.

sample could be seen below

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor

Comment: MVVM integration sucks on it, though...

Answer (score 4):

I found [ScintillaNET](https://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) rather pleasant for using and integration.